# OpenGL rendering images on VR headset

Tags: opencv, opengl, virtual-reality

I'm wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction for how I can render two separate images on to each eye of a HTC Vive device using OpenGL.

Basically, my ultimate aim is to stream from a ZED stereocamera (it has two lenses- each acts as an eye) on to the HTC Vive device.  However, I think my logical first step is to be able to render some static images.

Before anyone recommends Unity to achieve this- I have actually managed to get it to work there as it's much easier to get to grasps with.  It's just the rest of my python script (used for robot teleoperation) also accesses SteamVR to get controller co-ordinates so they fight over the one instance of SteamVR.... so I'm trying to find alternatives to make it work with my current python scripts.

I saw some code [here](https://github.com/cmbruns/pyopenvr/tree/master/src/openvr) which uses OpenGL to render a 3D environment & a cube on to the HTC device.  I got it display on my headset fine but now I'm stumped to how I render images instead of the cube. And due to my lack of knowledge in OpenGL and graphics programming, I'm not sure what exactly to look for in terms of helping me render images to each eye.

Could anyone please suggest some example codes or tutorials I could follow?  Thank you!

Comment: I would recommend doing a bsic opengl tutorial. By looking at an example that does a 3d scene, you are already adding on a ton of complexity. If you go through a basic opengl tutorial where you simply render a triangle to the screen you will be in much better shape. Rendering two images side by side is trivial with opengl, and is barely more than the initial setup. A basic opengl tutorial will give you everything you need.

Comment: @Luple ah okay. thanks for the heads up, I just used that example since it sets up the VR stuff nicely without me having to mess with a lot. so if I were to do the triangle thing as you suggested, would it be hard to display it on a VR device rather than the computer screen afterwards?

Comment: I just glanced through the example and am not familiar with openvr however it looks like all you need to worry about is the draw cube code, which is pretty straight foward opengl. The rest is just for setting up the VR matrices (since vr is basically creating two images by simulating two eyes as cameras. The scene itself is irrelevant. This is why just posting an image might be a little strange. An image has no depth which is going to mess with the simulated cameras. This is why I recommend getting more comfortable with opengl

Comment: Is there a documentation about how that 'fight' for the SteamVR instance is handled somewhere? I have a similar problem, but from the opposite perspective - I want transform-data from the headset in Unity, but I am rendering to it from another application.